# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Can anyone guide me to fix this issue.I am not sure why I am getting an error as below while on ***ionic serve*** :-

[image: Error I am getting]

My rootPage is Dashboard: 
Here is the code related to dashboard component.

dashboard.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
 @Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
 })
 export class DashboardPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:NavParams) {}

 ionViewDidLoad() {
 console.log('ionViewDidLoad DashboardPage');
}
}
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'dashboard'
})
export class DashboardComponent {

text: string;

constructor() {
   console.log('Hello Dashboard Component');
   this.text = 'Hello World';
 }

}
```

dashboard.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { DashboardPage } from './components/dashboard/dashboard';

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [,
      DashboardComponent,
      DashboardPage
   ],
  imports: [
  ],
 bootstrap: [IonicApp],
 entryComponents: [
   DashboardComponent,
   DashboardPage
 ],
 providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
  export class DashbaordModule {}
```

Comment: You need to first debug at which component it is happening. Specifically with which objects. Then paste that code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve your question lacks info for us to help. You should add _relevant code_.

Comment: Its not mentioning which component i am getting this..thats why i asked the chances of getting this error.

Comment: when ever you get this error it means that one of your object is not defined.

Comment: @suraj I have provided the code for my rootPage, I am not sure with which component its happening. Since the rootpage loads first, i hope there is a chance of getting this error in rootpage component. correct me if i am wrong, i am new to ionic2.

Comment: your `declarations: [,` starts with a comma. just a typo?

Comment: Ya..its typo ..sorry